# PowerBI Datamart size

Tags: powerbi

I am working on a project in PowerBI. We have created a datamart to store our data in the cloud. We have been trying to figure out the size of the datamart and cannot find any info anywhere. We know the limit is 100GB and want to make sure we don't hit that limit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Datamart is essentially a SQL DB. Run a query or connect to it using you favourite tool - see [Analyzing datamarts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/transform-model/datamarts/datamarts-analyze)